# How can I detect that a windows printer is printing to file

Tags: printing, driver

I have a service application that generates files to print as a result of user action. If the user selects a printer that "prints to file" the service hangs waiting for a file name to be supplied.  Is there anyway I can detect that the printer I am printing to is sending data to a file rather than a device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the name of the port that is connected to the queue. If the name is "FILE:", then windows will show a dialog asking for the output file name.

The user might of course also use some custom 3rd party port monitor, in that case you would need to go thru the window/dialogs for your process, and check if there is a modal dialog waiting for user input.

If it is a V4 printer driver, you can also check out the DriverCategory, if it is PrintFax.Fax, PrintFax.Printer.File, PrintFax.Printer.Virtual,...

Comment: Is there a way to detect that the printer is printing to a file even when it is a network printer?